# is it possible to create a form in the intranet that can be stored in a database?

Tags: database-design, ms-access

I am trying to create a form for my companies intraNet site. The idea is as follows:

1. An employee wants to make a purchase, so they will go to the appropriate page in the intraNet
2. They will fill out the form on the intraNet page
3. They click the email button
4. The data in the form is saved in a database, and an email is sent to me stating that there is purchase order request form filled out

I am not exactly sure how to go about this. Part of me wants to create it in a Data Access Page but I am not sure that's correct.

- Can someone help me?
- Is there anyone who can direct me to someone/something that can help me?

Comment: I cannot tell you too much about Access as programming languages, but for that kind of simpler stuff I preffer php, or ROR for development, that's my personal opinion, would be great if some DAP programmer share something with us.

Comment: There are new options available with Sharepoint and MS Access 2010, if they are available to you: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Access/Microsoft-Access-2010-Demo

Comment: You can build the web on your own. Take a look at the Express version of Visual Web Developer (FREE) http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express . To actually send the "form", please search for SmtpMail class and other related asp.net classes. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [APEX](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/cncptdev.htm#CNCPT7655) which is available even on the free [Oracle Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/overview/index.html).

> **Oracle Application Express** (APEX) is a Web application development
>   tool for Oracle Database. The tool uses built-in features such as user
>   interface themes, navigational controls, form handlers, and flexible
>   reports to accelerate application development.
>
> Oracle Application Express installs with the database and consists of
>   data in tables and PL/SQL code. When you run an application, your
>   browser sends a URL request that is translated into an Oracle
>   Application Express PL/SQL call. After the database processes the
>   PL/SQL, the results are relayed back to the browser as HTML. This
>   cycle happens each time you request or submit a page.
>
> You can use Oracle Application Express with the embedded PL/SQL
>   gateway. The gateway runs in the XML DB HTTP server in the database
>   and provides the necessary infrastructure to create dynamic
>   applications. As shown in Figure 19-1, the embedded PL/SQL gateway
>   simplifies the application architecture by eliminating the middle
>   tier.

You will need to evaluate this option with respect to your existing infrastructure and requirements.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I will look into it as much as I can! This really helps! :D

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to do this with Access. (Newer versions of these articles are probably available.)

- You can make a [data access page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140042%28v=office.10%29.aspx).
- If the database is accessible through a layer like ODBC, you can [link the tables to Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164914%28v=office.10%29.aspx). This would let employees use Access over the network; it wouldn't use the company's intranet.
- Use [Access + Sharepoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365trainingcourse_session-5_unit.aspx).
- Use a different Microsoft technology--[Visual Web Developer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178093%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). This would use the intranet without necessarily using Access.
- Use a [different rapid web application development technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rapid_application_development_tools#Web_Based_RAD_Tools) altogether.

Each of these has different trade-offs. Your decision will depend in part on what kind of dbms you're storing the data in--Access (Jet), SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc.